# Polymer JS reading from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, polymer

I'm trying to read a sub-array from a JSON file in Polymer in JS and return the sub-array to be used in a `dom-repeat`. However, it tells me that the sub-array is undefined. I tried re-structuring the JSON file in various ways but no luck. I think I'm not using the right syntax somewhere.

Right now the JSON looks like this:

```
{
        "url": "dn8",
        "volpage": "DN iii 1",
        "languages": [{
            "pt": {
                "authors": ["Laera"],
                "titlelan": "Title in Portuguese"
            },
            "fr": {
                "authors": ["Moi"],
                "titlelan": "Title in French"
            },
            "es": {
                "authors": ["Jesus"]
            }
        }]
}
```

I'm trying to get a sub-array called `languageData` which just hold the specific data for an input-language. The input has the correct value for the `inputLanguage`, like for instance "pt". My JS looks like this:

```
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-data',
      properties: {

        inputUrl: String,
        inputLanguage: String,
        inputData: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true,
              value: function(){return []}
        },

        languageData: {
          type: Array,
          computed: '_computeLanguage(inputData,inputLanguage)'
        }
      },
      _computeLanguage: function(inputData,inputLanguage) {
        var lanarray = inputData.languages[inputLanguage];
        return lanarray ? lanarray : "";
      }

    });
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you set up online example of the problem, it will be much easier to help then?
Here is how to do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/k4B2H0whGXROcvXnbx9y?p=preview

Comment: maybe try: `var lanarray = inputData.0.languages[inputLanguage];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the `languages` property of your JSON is not an `Object` but and `Array`.

Your "Polymer code" works well, the problem is that you are trying to get the `languageData` as if it were an Array:

```
var lanarray = inputData.languages[inputLanguage];
```

Actually, `languages` contains an array of objects and you can't find your lang object in this way.

A possible solution could be:

```
var lanarray = inputData.languages[0][inputLanguage];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That really helped and I can now see where I went wrong.